# How to remove the two words/characters between other two words/characters?

Tags: vim

In other words, how I turn this:

```
isDefault   預設      Default 初期設定
none    無       None    無
buyNow  現在購買        Buy now すぐ購入
```

into this?

```
isDefault 初期設定
none 無
buyNow すぐ購入
```

(Note that the spacing has to be turned into a single one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/\s.*\s/ /
```

- `\s.*\s` all characters from first whitespace up to last whitespace in the line
- replace this with single space

same concept with calling `awk` command

```
:%!awk '{print $1,$NF}'
```

will retain only first and last field